# gulp-sass : combine multiple scss into one scss file

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, angular13

I am using gulp npm package to bundle the scss files into one single scss file in angular 13. I am facing issues like,

**Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
╷
1 │ @use '@angular/material' as mat;**

Code:

```
gulp = require('gulp');
sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
combine = require('gulp-scss-combine');
concat = require('gulp-concat');
browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

// the default task
gulp.task('default', function () {
  return gulp.src('./lib/src/lib/theming/prebuilt/internal.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(concat('test-internal.scss'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/lib/theming/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({
      stream: true
    }))
});
```

In the internal.scss file there are lot imports there to other scss files. The ultimate goal is to process the internal.scss file and generate all the scss styles in one file that is (test-internal.scss).

Previously i had used scss-bundle and bundle-scss npm package but they are not working after angular 12 migration.

Comment: There's not a lot of info to go on, but it sounds like the SASS compiler can't find the `@angular/material` package. Try putting a tilde in front of the path: `@use '~@angular/material'`. This tells the compiler to look in `node_modules`. Are you using node-sass or Dart sass?

Comment: @jla  the above code is in angular 13. so in angular 13 automatically the ~ will be removed when migration runs.

Comment: Interesting. I suppose you've tried putting a relative path to the angular package? eg `@use '../../../../../node_modules/@angular/material/_index.scss'` or whatever the path to the file should be. Your gulpfile looks fine to me. I'm not sure you need to use concat, but it's probably not causing any issues as the sass compiler runs first